# Is there a smog abatement program for repairs greater than a certain amount in california?

Tags: subaru, obd-ii, registration

I just bought a used car, and I'm going to get it smogged soon.  Apparently (this is what the mechanic said), I can't get it smogged until 2 "checks" turn on.  I think this means that the check engine light may or may not come on soon, but I need to drive it until its activated or something.

My question is, if the check engine light comes on and the repairs are going to be expensive, is there a smog abatement fee I can pay so that I can skip the repairs?  It was a very cheap car, and I don't want to have to pay more on repairs than I paid for the car.

Let me know if this question is not in the scope of this beta, and I will remove it.  Any additional information (e.g. what are the "checks" he's talking about?) will be helpful.

The car is a 1996 Subaru Legacy Outback.

Comment: I'm not from CA, but I remember someone from there once telling me that when the repairs reached a certain dollar value (maybe based on percent of the vehicles value) that they had a choice of paying a fee and just buying the cert even though it didn't pass, or they could scrap it and get some money towards a new car.

Comment: I *think* that what the mechanic is referring to is that the check engine light and probably the ABS light are coming on for a few seconds when you start the engine. They're obviously supposed to go out after a few seconds...

Comment: Oh, and a quick look on the Internet suggests that there aren't any ways to get around the requirement for the smog check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the vehicle is a 96, the mechanic might have meant that you need 2 or 2 more [OBDII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II) monitor readiness checks.  Some emissions systems are checked continuously by the powertrain controller, while others are only checked periodically when certain driving conditions are met ([FAQ](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.bar.ca.gov/80_BARResources/ftp/pdfdocs/obd_ii_faqs.pdf&ei=R7x3T-__EqSHsAK8u4iiBA&sa=X&oi=unauthorizedredirect&ct=targetlink&ust=1333248847313067&usg=AFQjCNEg_S77OQwxhq1hlRWAJjOf-MQ5sA)).

Has your battery been disconnected?  That could have reset the monitoring status.  It can be done from a scan tool, also.  If the previous owner reset the system with a scan tool before you bought the car, that's obviously not a good sign and the vehicle might need some emissions work.

Normally you're good to go for emissions testing after a couple days of driving after a reset/power loss.

As Timo Geusch is suggesting, I don't think there is a way around passing an emission test if you want to keep the car on the road.  However, there is a [program](http://www.smogcheck.ca.gov/80_BARResources/01_CAP&GoldShield/cap_program.html) that offers up to $500 of financial assistance toward emissions repairs (if you qualify).

[Supposedly](http://www.city-data.com/forum/los-angeles/787574-bought-used-car-wont-pass-smog.html), though, you should have gotten a current smog certificate at the time of sale.  It sounds like you can go after the seller.

Comment: thanks, I actually did end up going after the seller, who was able to pay $150 in smog maintenance repairs.  All is good now.